# ActiveMQ + NFS race condition

Tags: design-patterns, activemq-classic, messaging, apache-camel, nfs

I am using ActiveMQ on a cluster of computers to send messages between java processes.

The cluster has a shared NFS mount accessible from all hosts.

I am running into problems with the following scenario:

- host A creates a new file "/path/to/shared/nfs/xyz"
- host A sends a message to host B: "process /path/to/shared/nfs/xyz"
- host B receives the message, attempts to open the file
- host B fails because NFS client has not yet noticed that a new file was previously created on A (race condition between ActiveMQ and the NFS protocol)

My solution is to add a loop into all message receivers that would wait up to 1 minute for the NFS to realize a new file was added.

This solution however seems unclean. What would be a good way of solving this? Do you know of any enterprise integration design patterns that apply?

Comment: i assume the file is too big to send via jms?  how big is it?

Answer (score 2):

another thought is to just have host B be a file polling consumer that picks up anything that is placed in "/path/to/shared/nfs/xyz" and processes it...that way you don't need any messaging from A to B to initiated it, just the presence of the file.

you can do still easily using something like [Apache Camel's file component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)...

```
from("file://path/to/shared/nfs/xyz").to(...);
```

Comment: this is nice.  that way their is only one protocol being used and no race condition.